# Checking which class was selected in jquery

Tags: jquery, css, class

If you have an element with two classes applied to it, how can you check what the second class was?

For example:

```
class="class1 abc"
class="class1 xyz"
```

When class1 is clicked, how can you check what the second class was, so you can redirect to appropriate action?

```
 $('.class1').click(function() { 
     // ** var secondClass = abc | xyz
     // ** do something if second class was abc, or something else if second class was xyz **
```

Comment: Who do I give the accepted answer to? They are all the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('.class1').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('abc')) {
        //...
    } else {
        //...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)..

```
$('.class1').click(function() {
    if($this.hasClass("xyz")){
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the element [has a particular class](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/), like this:

```
$(this).hasClass("abc")
```

and redirect based on that.

Answer (score 2):

Use the this keyword and has class within your click handler.

For example:

```
$('.class1').click(function() {
    // the this keyword is rewritten to the matching element by jQuery automatically
    // cache the jQuery object for this
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.hasClass('abc')) {
    } else if ($this.hasClass('xyz')) {
    } else {
    }
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.class1').click(function(){
   if($(this).hasClass('abc'))
   {
    //do something
   }else if($(this).hasClass('xyz'))
   {
     //do something else

   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

How about checking for the existence of the class:

```
$('.class1').click(function() { 
  var hasABC = $(this).hasClass('abc');
  var hasXYZ = $(this).hasClass('xyz');
  // ... do real work now ...
}
```